# Habilitar/Deshabilitar Checkboxes haciendo click en otro checkbox diferente usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

estoy desarrollando un formulario que contiene una lista de checkbox, los cuales pertenecen a la clase **.causa**, así mismo existe un checkbox de la clase **.sin_causa** el cual pretendo que deshabilite los checkbox mencionados inicialmente. Buscando en Internet me encontré con el siguiente ejemplo, el cual sólo permite deshabilitar a los checkbox sin importar de qué clase sea al que se haga click:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    if ($(".sin_causa").is(':checked') ) {
        $( ".causa" ).prop( "disabled", false );
        alert('Unchecked');
    } else {
        $( ".causa" ).prop( "disabled", true );
        alert('Checked');
    }
});
```

```html
<tr>
  <th rowspan="1">Propuesta Económica</th>
  <td>Los precios de sus productos son elevados</td>
  <td><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input class="form-check-input causa" type="checkbox" value="22" id="causas[]" name="causas[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th rowspan="2">Personal</th>
  <td>El particular autorizado/concesionado no se encuentra en el Establecimiento de Consumo Escolar.</td>
  <td><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input class="form-check-input causa" type="checkbox" value="23" id="causas[]" name="causas[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>El personal que labora en el Establecimeinto tiene actitudes negativas y presta sus servicios de mal forma. </td>
  <td><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input class="form-check-input causa" type="checkbox" value="24" id="causas[]" name="causas[]"></td>
</tr>

<label><strong>*En caso de no resultar problemática alguna, de click en la siguiente casilla.</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="25" id="sin_causa[]" name="sin_causa[]"></label>
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda, así como orientación que pudieran brindarme...

Comment: Creo que se trataría de leer primero ése valor del objeto $(this) para luego actuar en consecuéncia, pero necesitaría ver la parte html para asegurarme, ¿puedes publicarla?

Comment: Acabo de agregar parte del formulario, ya que es demaciado extenso

Comment: Aunque agregue la clase sin_causa al checkbox o lo use mediante su id no ejecuta la acción, de ahí mi duda

Comment: Yo creo que más bien se trataría de usar hasClass para saber qué clase es $(this) y cambiar el otro condicional para que tome la consideración según la clase de éste y no tome la decisión según su estado. Es decir, el if is(':checked') es el que determina si cambiar el estado y por tanto eso está mal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según creo entender en la pregunta, el efecto que busca es más bien:

```js
        $('#sin_causa').on('change', function() {
             if ($(this).is(':checked') ) {
                $( ".causa" ).prop( "disabled", true );
             } else {
                $( ".causa" ).prop( "disabled", false );
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="1">Propuesta Económica</th>
            <td>Los precios de sus productos son elevados</td>
            <td><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input class="form-check-input causa" type="checkbox" value="22" id="causas[]" name="causas[]"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Personal</th>
            <td>El particular autorizado/concesionado no se encuentra en el Establecimiento de Consumo Escolar.</td>
            <td><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input class="form-check-input causa" type="checkbox" value="23" id="causas[]" name="causas[]"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>El personal que labora en el Establecimeinto tiene actitudes negativas y presta sus servicios de mal forma. </td>
            <td><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input class="form-check-input causa" type="checkbox" value="24" id="causas[]" name="causas[]"></td>
        </tr>
        <label><strong>*En caso de no resultar problemática alguna, de click en la siguiente casilla.</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="25" id="sin_causa" name="sin_causa"></label>
    </table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! En verdad me funciono como esperaba :)

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias varias metodologias, puedes usar las clases, o a su vez el id, te dare un ejemplo donde uso el ID

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_1" checked><label>Checkbox 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_2" checked><label>Checkbox 2</label>
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_3" onclick="miFuncion(event);"><label>Marcar/Desmarcar</label>
<script>
function miFuncion(event){
if ($('#chk_1').is(":checked")){
//quitamos los seleccionados
$('#chk_1').attr('checked', false);
$('#chk_2').attr('checked', false);
}else{
//seleccionamos
$('#chk_1').attr('checked', true);
$('#chk_2').attr('checked', true);
}
}//end function 
</script>
```

[Ejemplo realizado !!](https://jsfiddle.net/adxpe0yp/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Ya casi lo tienes, solo te falta agregar el evento onchange al checkbox con  el id `"sin_causa[]"` para que active o desactive los demás checkbox con la clase `"causa"`

partiendo de tu código, aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo:

```js
$('#sin_causa').on('change', function() {
        $( ".causa" ).prop( "disabled", $(this).is(':checked'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <th rowspan="1">Propuesta Económica</th>
  <td>Los precios de sus productos son elevados</td>
  <td><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input class="form-check-input causa" type="checkbox" value="22" id="causas[]" name="causas[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th rowspan="2">Personal</th>
  <td>El particular autorizado/concesionado no se encuentra en el Establecimiento de Consumo Escolar.</td>
  <td><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input class="form-check-input causa" type="checkbox" value="23" id="causas[]" name="causas[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>El personal que labora en el Establecimeinto tiene actitudes negativas y presta sus servicios de mal forma. </td>
  <td><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input class="form-check-input causa" type="checkbox" value="24" id="causas[]" name="causas[]"></td>
</tr>

<label><strong>*En caso de no resultar problemática alguna, de click en la siguiente casilla.</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="25" id="sin_causa" name="sin_causa"></label>
```

Solo un ultimo consejo, no uses caracteres especiales en los nombres o id como por ejemplo los corchetes [].

Espero esto te ayude. ;))...

Comment: Muchas gracias :)